# Solving an Inequality that contains many unknown variables

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

So, I'm a beginner in using mathematica, can do only the basic stuff... anyway, I want to find the bound for [pi], that makes this quantity

2 ((n - y)Log[(n - y)]+yLog[ y_]-yLog[n[Pi]] - (n - y) Log[n - n [Pi]o])

less than a known value (chi). taking in mind that n and y are unknowns.

I have tried it for given values of n and y and it gives a bound perfectly, but for some reason it do not give a general bound when n and y are unknown
here is a screenshot on what i have done. 
[image]

```
y = 0; n = 25; 
\[Pi]o =.; \[Alpha] = 0.05; df = 1; 
chi = Quantile[ChiSquareDistribution[df], 1 - \[Alpha]]; 
An = 2 ((n - y) Log[(n - y)] + y Log[ y_] - y Log[n \[Pi]o] - (n - y) Log[n - n \[Pi]o]); 
AA = 2 ((m - x) Log[(m - x)] + x Log[x_] - x Log[m [Pi]o] - (m - x) Log[m - m \[Pi]o]); 
Reduce[An <= chi, \[Pi]o, Reals] Reduce [{AA < chi, m >= x >= 0}, \[Pi]o, Reals]
```

so An is the formula when the values (n and y) are known and AA is the term when the values are unknown (m is n and x is y)

Comment: Code that can't be copied by others prevents you from getting helped. Post copyable code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: y = 0; n = 25; \[Pi]o =.;
\[Alpha] = 0.05; df = 1; chi = 
 Quantile[ChiSquareDistribution[df], 1 - \[Alpha]];

An = 2 ((n - y) Log[(n - y)] + y Log[ y_] - 
     y Log[n \[Pi]o] - (n - y) Log[n - n \[Pi]o]);

AA = 2 ((m - x) Log[(m - x)] + x Log[x] - 
     x Log[m \[Pi]o] - (m - x) Log[m - m \[Pi]o]);

Reduce[An <= chi, \[Pi]o, Reals]
Reduce [{AA < chi, m >= x >= 0}, \[Pi]o, Reals]

Comment: thanks for the tip... appreciate it

Comment: Luckily another user has edited your post for you. Next time, edit your post to include code; don't leave it in a comment.

Comment: You have y_ and x_ in your An and AA. _ has a very special definition in MMA and can't be used in ordinary variable names. So you want to change those. After that you have y=0 and y* Log[y] = 0* -Infinity and MMA doesn't know what to do with that. If you can resolve all these then someone can suggest the next step.